# Working with ESRI shapefiles in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, shapefile

Couldn't find a solution on google or here at stackoverflow ...

Anyone knows how can a I handle ESRI shapefiles in android? I'm trying to build a simple shape viewer (for now it's not necessary to write/create shp), and maybe later overlap the maps on top of google maps on android.

So far I tried openMaps and GeoTools, but with no success. Reading the shapefile and store it inside a SQLite database is also interesting! In fact, so far what I'm doing right now is converting the shapefile to a CSV (outside android, in a computer) and then reading the CSV to SQLite for later reading inside the App.

But it would be very interesting if I could read directly from shape to SQLite (or Shape -> csv -> SQLite) using only android.

Any ideas how can I do that? I don't have much experience with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making use of [Shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org/), which is part of [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org/).  You will need to use the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) but GDAL is an excellent library with a great community / support and used by [many programs](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/SoftwareUsingGdal).

I made a quick [demo](https://github.com/snodnipper/shapelib-android-demo) to write / append to a shapefile, which should be a sufficient starting point.  Please fork the demo if you would like to enhance it for your needs.

Comment: How to import GDAL/OGR in android project? To import it using NDK there should be CMakeLists.txt file. Do I need to create it? If yes then how? Is it possible on windows?  I have seen that it requires UNIX OS.